# How can I use Julia's StaticArrays.SMatrix from Python

Tags: python, julia

I am trying to run Julia code from Python. I am confused about how I should run

```
mat = SMatrix{2, 2}([1 2; 3 4])
```

In Python? I was trying

```py
from julia import StaticArrays as sa

mat = sa.SMatrix{2, 2}([1 2; 3 4])
```

And as I expected, I got the error

```
*** SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any idea what I should do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using the [`julia.py`](https://pyjulia.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) package, you can use the following syntax:

```py
In [1]: from julia import Main as jl

In [2]: jl.eval("using StaticArrays")

In [3]: mat = jl.eval("SMatrix{2, 2}([1 2; 3 4])")

In [4]: mat
Out[4]: [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

And suppose you're working in an IPython environment or a Jupyter NoteBook: you can activate the %julia magic command and continue with writing Julia codes with Julia syntax without using strings:

```py
In [5]: %load_ext julia.magic
Initializing Julia interpreter. This may take some time...

# Note that I've imported the StaticArrays in previous cells
# by `jl.eval("using StaticArrays")`
In [6]: %julia SMatrix{2, 2}([1 2;3 4])
Out[6]: [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

# Also, it is possible to load any package with this magic command:
# In [7]: %julia using StaticArrays
# will load the package if installed in the activated julia environment.
```

Or, you use the [`juliacall`](https://docs.juliahub.com/PythonCall/WdXsa/0.5.0/juliacall/) and write the following:

```
In [1]: from juliacall import Main as jl

In [2]: jl.seval("using StaticArrays")

In [3]: mat = jl.seval("SMatrix{2, 2}([1 2; 3 4])")

In [4]: mat
Out[4]:
2×2 SMatrix{2, 2, Int64, 4} with indices SOneTo(2)×SOneTo(2):
 1  2
 3  4
```